# Digital Asset Links does not work without a trailing dot

Tags: android, firebase-hosting, digital-assets-links

| Expample |  |
| --- | --- |
| App link | `https://example.web.app` |
| Package Name | `com.example.android` |

### Overview

Questions about the development of AppLink.

Deploy `.well-known/assetlinks.json`, and now viewable via digital link(ex. `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.web.app&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`)

The fllowing is its json:

```json
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "source": {
        "web": {
          "site": "https://example.web.app."
        }
      },
      "relation": "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "target": {
        "androidApp": {
          "packageName": "com.example.android",
          "certificate": {
            "sha256Fingerprint": "xxx"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "maxAge": "3596.313666292s"
}
```

Then, in Android emulator, I tried to open by `adb` command.

Of course, we also set the intent-filter, in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.web.app" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.web.app" />
```

```bash
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.web.app"
```

But it simply opened the browser, but not the app.

Then, I tried the URL with a dot(`.`) at the end and succeeded in opening the app!

```bash
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.web.app."
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

Add dot at the end

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.web.app." />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.web.app." />
```

I want to make a successful transition to the application without a trailing dot, any good solution?

Pardon my poor English.

Thank you.

### Environment

#### Native App

- Flutter: 3.13.5

#### Web Hosting

- Firebase Hosting

#### Web Frontend

- Next.js: 13.4.7

### Setting Files

```json
// public/.well-known/assetlinks.json

[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.example.android",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["xxx"]
    },
  }
]
```

```json
// firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type", 
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type", 
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

### Note

I think I have done the required settings.

- Deploy `.well-known/assetlinks.json`

  - Add SHA256 fingerprint
  - See statements list in https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/...
- Add `intent-filter`

  - android:autoVerify="true"
- Flutter run, in release build